# Which is the best way to communicate between a Unix Host and a Windows Client?

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, debian

I'm currently working on a small C#-based client tool, which can perform some actions on my debian homeserver via LAN, like scanning and printing. To this point I'm using common interfaces like SANE and CUPS and predefined libraries, like SaneSharpLib etc.

Now, I want to get some custom information from the server-system, like the status of some processes or (external) devices.

Which is the best (easy vs. resource-efficient) way  to create a network based communication channel between these systems to transfer these kind of data?

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way to do this, is connecting to your host via ssh and get the information you need, like you do it directly on your system.

Try this to bound ssh to your c# app.

http://sshnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: I had the same idea sooner, but this would mean, that all requests will be stored in the client tool. When I will change the server system for any reason, then I have to update all clients. For this reason I would prefer an interface, or something like that...

Comment: So you mean changing from unix to windows? what you can also do is setting up a webserver with a webpage as interface in the background you can have a cgi applikation which will generate your information. changing the server operating system will cause the cgi programm to change. the webrequest on the page will be steady in the client

Comment: By "changing the system" I meant, to change something on the system configuration, like upgrading to another version, which can result in other requests etc. Are you sure, that I can get system and device information through an cgi application?

Comment: cgi can be used with standard c applikation. so what ever you can do with c on your system, cgi can bind it to a webpage. but when you will stay on linux you can use ssh. may be you can tell about which information you want to send.